# Rewrite www.domainnamenumberone.com/wordpress/path/ to domaintwo.com/wordpress/path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two domain names for the same website, and need to do a correct rewrite, so that whenever someone accesses the first domain name and all subdirectories, with, or without www. they get redirected to the second domain and subdirectories without www.

I managed to set the redirect for the domain name without subdirectories, but for whatever reason, subdirectories are not getting rewritten.

So when I go to domainnamenumberone.com, or www.domainnamenumberone.com, i get redirected to domaintwo.com – however, when I go to  domainnamenumberone.com/wordpress/path or www.domainnamenumberone.com/wordpress/path I remain there, and nothing gets rewritten.

Here's what I placed in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainnumberone\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domaintwo.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainnumberone\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domaintwo.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domaintwo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domaintwo.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place this rule as **very first rule** in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domaintwo\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainnumberone\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domaintwo.com/%1 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Then add this line in each child .htaccess like `wordpress/` or `wordpress/path/` (wherever .htaccess already exists) below `RewriteEngine On` line

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you, @anubhava!

Comment: @anubhava I do not understand what was the problem and why `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}...`

Comment: @Croises: Problem was presence of multiple .htaccess. 1) root 2) wordpress And the reason why I chose `%{THE_REQUEST}` because I suggested used of `RewriteOptions Inherit` to avoid duplicating this rule in both .htaccess. Pls note that `REQUEST_URI` based rule will give wrong results in this case because parent .htaccess is inherited after execution of child .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainnumberone\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domaintwo.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it seems to me that it should also work with yours.....
try a different browser (cache problem)

Comment: Nope, nothing is changing, and the issue manifests itself in all browsers.